# Replace "words" automatically in microsoft word

Tags: ms-word

Normally I copy/paste text into MS and after that I go to "replace" feature and I replace the words manually.

I was wondering if there's a way of doing that automatically, so when I paste the text the words changes directly. Is that even possible?

Thanks all.

Comment: ...Unless you are planning to write a program to do it you're in the wrong place...

Comment: You may want to record a macro (enable the Developer tab first).

Comment: The words you want to replace are always the same ? Can you please give a concrete example, I'm not sure I understand

Comment: Yes the words are always the same. Like Alonso = Alonzo.